# How does nullification of $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$ compare to 1-truncation?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, infinity-topos-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Let $B$ be a type (or space). A type (or space) is *$B$-null* if the canonical map $X \to X^B$ is an equivalence. The *$B$-nullification* of an arbitrary type $X$ is a $B$-null type $\bigcirc_B X$ together with a map $\eta_X: X \to \bigcirc_B X$ such that for any $B$-null type $Y$ the map $Y^{\bigcirc_B X} \to Y^X$ given by composition with $\eta_X$ is an equivalence.

In particular being $\mathbb{S}^2$-null is the same as being 1-truncated, and $\mathbb{S}^2$-nullification is exactly 1-truncation.

$\mathbb{S}^2$ has non trivial homotopy groups above dimension 2. We can eliminate these higher homotopy groups by taking the 2-truncation of $\mathbb{S}^2$. This gives us the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$, which has $\pi_2$ equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ and all other homotopy groups trivial.

I would like to know how $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$-nullification compares to 2-truncation. Certainly, $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$ is 1-connected, which tells us some other things like $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$-connected implies 1-connected, and that 1-truncated implies $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$-null, but there's not much else I can see at the moment, including some basic things:

1. Is $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$-nullification the same as 1-truncation?
2. Is $\mathbb{S}^2$ $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$-null?
3. Is $\mathbb{S}^2$ $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$-connected (i.e. has trivial nullification)?

NB: I had homotopy type theory in mind for this question, because that's what I'm more familiar with. See Rijke, Shulman, Spitters, *[Modalities in homotopy type theory](https://doi.org/10.23638/LMCS-16(1:2)2020)* for details on nullification in this setting and Licata, Finster, *[Eilenberg-MacLane Spaces in Homotopy Type Theory](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2603088.2603153)* for Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

However, I think that the question also makes sense for $\infty$-toposes and other approaches to homotopy theory, where the answer might be more well known and I would also be interested to hear such answers in those settings.

Comment: This modality is briefly discussed in Example 6.1 in [_Cellular properties of nilpotent spaces_](https://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2015.19.2741) where they show that $S^3$ is not $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$-connected.

Comment: I wonder how this interacts with the Sullivan Conjecture (which was proved by Miller)?  That implies that if $X$ is a space with $p$-complete homotopy groups and $G$ is a finite $p$-group then $X$ is $BG$-null.  Up to $p$-completion, the space $K(\mathbb{Z},2)=\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is the colimit of the spaces $B(\mathbb{Z}/p^k)$.  Also, there is a cofibration $B(\mathbb{Z}/p^k)\to \mathbb{C}P^\infty\to T$, where $T$ is the Thom space of the $p^k$th tensor power of the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$.  I don't know how Thomification interacts with nullity.

Comment: @UlrikBuchholtz I think that answers the question, right? Because if $\mathbb{S}^2$ was $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$-connected, then every 1-connected space would be $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$-connected, including $\mathbb{S}^3$. For the same reason, it seems that showing $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$-connected should be easier than $\mathbb{S}^3$, so I'm wondering if there's a more direct proof?